# change where clause of query based on different input laravel 5.6

Tags: sql, laravel, controller, where-clause

how to change the where condition of query based on different input in laravel 
controller.

for example if i have law_id as input then the where condition

should use this law_id and fetch data.

this is my code:

```
$law_id = Input::get('law_id');
$subject_matter = Input::get('subject_matter');
$case_no = Input::get('case_no');
$court = Input::get('court');
$legal_data = DB::table('tbl_legal_form')->select('*');
if($law_id != '')
{
   $legal_data = $legal_data->where('legal_applicable_law',$law_id);
}
if($subject_matter != '')
{
   $legal_data = $legal_data->where('subject_matter',$subject_matter);
}
$result = $legal_data->get();
```

What is the best way to do this..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$legal_data = DB::table('tbl_legal_form');
if($law_id != '')
{
 $legal_data = $legal_data->where('legal_applicable_law',$law_id)->get();
}
if($subject_matter != '')
{
  $legal_data = $legal_data->where('subject_matter',$subject_matter)->get();
}
$result = $legal_data;
```